# How do I find the first number that divides with the first 20 numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, loops

I want to find the smallest number that can be divided with no reminder(perfect division) by the first 20 numbers (1, 2, 3... 20).

I've tried something that I thought would not fail, that goes like this:

```
for (int i = 20; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
    int seImparte = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j <= 20; j++) {
        if (i % j != 0) {
            seImparte++;
        }
    }
    if (seImparte == 0) {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```

I thought I would get the first number and then the program would exit, but it runs and nothing happens.

Thank you for your time and help!

Comment: "nothing happens", or it just doesn't find such a number. how about you print which number you test, in addition with for which divisions there is a remainder. You are aware that this number has to be pretty high? Sure it's even possible within the range of Integer? why don't you first check with the first three/four/five/... numbers, just to check whether your logic works

Comment: @Stultuske maybe you are right and the number is not withing the Integer limits and I will try doing it different now. The program works, you are right, it's just that the number it is so big I believe that it just didn't find it yet

Comment: @JoakimDanielson that is not divisible by 20. Not without a remainder, anyway. Nor by 12.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry, but that is not the number

Comment: This can be solved very easily without programming. Highest occurrences of prime 2 below 20 is 16 = 2^4, for 3 it is 9 or 18 (2 occurrences), and for the rest of the primes below 20 the highest occurrence is 1. So the solution is: 2^4 * 3^2 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@raulGLD Your code **works fine but it is not optimezed**,

You can **break inner loop**, after invalid condition
Also you **can start from 3 or 7** as [1,2,3,4,5,6 can be tested by [4,6,8,10,12]
 -**This is optional but break is important**

```
     for (int i = 20; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
      int seImparte = 0;
        for (int j = 7; j <= 20; j++) {
            if (i % j != 0) {
                seImparte++; break;
            }
        }
        if (seImparte == 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

output : 232792560

Comment: Yup, you are right, thank you. The problem was it was doing way too many things to work fast. I did what you suggested and I got the right answer! Thank you.

Comment: Some time just solution is not enough we need to find optimized solutions

Comment: Not optimized enough though. See MBo's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of optimizing of brute-force approach, it is worth to use simple math rules.

Resulting complexity is `O(n*log(n))` against "huge count"

Python code uses [Least common multiple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) function

```
def gcd(a, b):
    while b > 0:
        a, b = b, a % b
    return a

def lcm(a, b):
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)     # integer division


d = 1
for i in range(2, 21): #last i=20
    d = lcm(d, i)

print(d)

>>[Dbg]>>> 232792560
```

Also we can make factorization of all numbers in range into primes and remember the largest powers for every prime. In this case: `2:4; 3:2; 5:1; 7:1; 11:1; 13:1; 17:1; 19:1` and multiply these powers. More complex code (but this way might be useful sometimes)

```
232792560 = 16 * 9 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19
```

Comment: OP want Java and do not want to use math but brute force.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste Yunès  Question is tagged with `algorithm`, so it would be nice to show better way. Java or not - is not important, enough to know  that "LCM" helps to avoid time wasting. Do you believe that this answer is harmful?

Comment: I doubt OP knows what "algorithm" tag means, he tagged java first and as he thought he had problem with his algorithm he tagged so.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you are looking:

```
for (int i = 2; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= 20; j++) {
            if (i % j == 0) {
                System.out.println("i : "+i+" j : "+j);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you don't explain what went wrong or what you did different, so not really